# How to use graph structure effectively for a special aviation graph like use case?

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, guava

I want a graph to manage routes between the nodes similar to Aviation(flights) graph but here the nodes are of three different types A, B, C (like Countries, States, Cities) such that several Cs make B and several Bs make A but the glitch is unlike Aviation where edges are from city to city and other two play role in like adjacency list, here the edges can go across any of the A, B, C irrespective of whom the compose.

The final intent of the graph is to have a sequence of Cs to process considering the order of Bs As and the edges between all A, B, Cs.

I tried with 3*3 edge types but the traversal still needs jugglery. Is there any cleaner solution to this?

Comment: Could you show us your code and point out what's not working as expected?